# how to avoid client side computation in EF Core

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.2

As far as I understand EF Core will run some actions locally when they can't be translated to raw sql commands / tsql.
How can we disable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent client evaluation of your queries, you can override the OnConfiguring event of the DbContext. Here is an example:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warning =>
        {
            warning.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning);
        });
    }
}
```

This configuration will throw an exception anytime you attempt a query that will be evaluated on the client.